# A sequence satisfying $\lvert f_{i+j}-f_i-f_j\rvert \leq M$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ be a sequence s.t
$$(\exists M\geq 0)(\forall i,j\in\mathbb N)(\lvert f_{i+j}-f_i-f_j\rvert \leq M) $$
Must such a sequence be bounded?
No, it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A keyword in this question is *Hyers-Ulam* stability. From the condition in the question one may derive by induction that $\vert f_{n m}-n f_m\vert\leq (n-1)M $. This implies $\vert n f_m-m f_n\vert\leq (n+m-2)M$. Diving by $nm$ shows that the sequence $\left(\frac{f_n}{n}\right)$ is Cauchy.  More exactly $\vert\frac{f_n}{n}-\frac{f_m}{m}\vert\leq\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}\right) M (+)$. Let the *real* number $f$ its limit. Then $(+)$ for $m\to\infty$ shows that $\vert\frac{f_n}{n}-f\vert\leq \left(\frac{1}{n}+0\right) M$ or $\vert f_n-n f\vert\leq M$. Thus $f_n=n f+r_n$ with  some bounded sequence of real numbers $r_n$ such that $n f+r_n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For example, for any real $c$, the sequence of $f_n$ with $f_n=[c n]$ (the greatest integer not greater than $c n$ satisfies the original inequality with $M=2$ since $x=[x]+ r_x$ with $0\leq r_x<1$.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting!

Comment: Conversely, does such a sequence exist for every $f\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Put $f_n=n f$. But then $f_n$ is not necessarily contained in $\mathbb{Z}$. The example in the answer gives an integer valued sequence of $f_n$ with $f=c$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, this answers my original question and even more!

Comment: @AlvinLepik If you want more information on this subject, I would be glad to share my knowledge on this topic with you.

Comment: I have an exercise to identify real numbers with equivalence classes of sequences described in 1st post. Taking $f_n\sim g_n$ if the sequence $f_n-g_n$ is bounded as $n\to\infty$ provides an equivalence relation which is compatible with addition, but it fails to be compatible with pointwise multiplication. I think your answer has a way around it, but I need to work out the details first :)

Comment: Multiplication is more difficult. If you are interested, send me an email at the address in the profile. I wrote something exactly on this topic one year ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74946/discussion-between-jens-schwaiger-and-alvin-lepik).

Answer (score 5):

No such a sequence does not have to be bounded:

Consider $f_n = n$. Then $|f_{i+j} -f_i - f_j| = 0$, but $f_n \to \infty$.

Comment: of course * smacks forehead *