# Let $(x_n)$ be a $\epsilon$-additive sequence. Prove that $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\frac{x_m}{m} = L$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Problem**

Let $(x_n)$ be a $\epsilon$-additive sequence, that is, given $\epsilon>0$ , $\forall \, m,n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow |x_{m+n}-x_m-x_n|\leq \epsilon$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{m \to  \infty}\frac{x_m}{m} = L$ exists. Do so following these five steps:

1. Define $(y_n)$, with general term $y_n = \frac{x_{2^n}}{2^n}$. Prove this is Cauchy.
2. Using induction, prove that $\forall \, m \in \mathbb{N}, \, m >1$ we can write, uniquely, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$m=a_02^0+a_12^1+\cdots+a_{n-1}2^{n-1}+2^n \quad\quad a_i = 0 \text{ or }1$$
3. Using induction, prove that if $m= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{a_i{2^i}}+2^n$ we have $$\left|x_m -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{a_ix_{2^i}} - x_{2^n}\right| \leq \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{a_i}\right)\epsilon $$
4. Using the expression in step 3, prove that $\lim\limits_{m \to  \infty}\frac{x_m}{m} = L$, where $L$ is the limit in step 1
5. Verify that $\left|\frac{x_m}{m}-L\right|\leq \epsilon$ for all $m$

I was able to prove step 2, but I'm stuck in the rest. I've noticed this problem has been posted here already, but I failed to see any answers similar to what I need.

Please verify if those steps are indeed correct, and if possible, give me a hint for step 1. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to follow this proof, and I got stuck in part 4. If you can give me a solution or a good hint for 4. I give you the bounty.

Comment: @Marcos: It seems that the question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2703701/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check (1) first you prove that $|x_{km}-kx_m| <= k\epsilon$
This is done by induction, for k = 1 it is clearly true.
Assuming its validity for k, we have
$|x_{(k+1)m} - (k+1)x_m| = |x_{(k+1)m} - x_{km} -x_m + x_{km} + x_m - (k+1)x_k| <=
 |x_{(k+1)m} - x_{km} -x_m| + |x_{km} + x_m - (k+1)x_k| <=
\epsilon + |x_{km} - kx_k| <= \epsilon + k\epsilon = (k+1)\epsilon$
The first estimation is from additivity of the sequence, the second from induction assumption.

With this, we have for $k = 2^{m-n}$

$|x_{2^m} - (2^{m-n})x_{2^n}|= |x_{2^{m-n}2^n}- (2^{m-n})x_{2^n}| <= 2^{m-n}\epsilon$

Hence, dividing both sides by $2^m$ we get:

$|\frac{x_{2^m}}{2^m} - \frac{x_{2^n}}{2^n}| <= 2^{-n}\epsilon$

This shows that $y_m$ is Cauchy, i.e. that for any $\delta > 0$ one can find k such that
$|y_p - y_q| < \delta$ if $p$ and $q$ are bigger than $k$.